# Cross product in 4 dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, products

Cross product is defined in three dimensions the resulting vector have the same **magnitude** as the *area* of the parallelogram formed by the 2 multiplied vectors and its direction **direction** is **perpendicular** to the first two vectors. so **Can we come up with an equation using the same analogy but in 4-dimensional space**(so that the resulting vector's magnitude is the volume of the parallelepiped formed by the three input vectors and it's direction is -somehow- perpendicular to the first three vectors)?

Comment: as you will see in some of the answers at the earlier version of this question, you can put your three vectors as three rows of a 4 by 4 matrix. Then make up new variables, maybe $W,X,Y,Z,$ and put those variables as the fourth row. Find the determinant of the 4 by 4 matrix, which is a polynomial $c_W W + c_X X + c_Y Y + c_Z Z.$ Your desired vector is $(c_W, c_X, c_Y, c_Z)$

Comment: parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? h = [ 1,2,3,5; 7,11,13,17; 19,23,29,31; w,x,y,z]
%1 = 
[ 1  2  3  5]

[ 7 11 13 17]

[19 23 29 31]

[ w  x  y  z]

? poly = matdet(h)
%2 = 8*x + (-70*w + (78*y - 36*z))
? col 
%3 = col
? col = [ -70; 8; 78; -36]
%4 = 
[-70]

[  8]

[ 78]

[-36]

? h * col
%5 = 
[                            0]

[                            0]

[                            0]

[8*x + (-70*w + (78*y - 36*z))]

?